# How to read a string stream in Java discarding illegal characters?

Tags: java, parsing, text

I have to parse a stream of bytes coming from a TCP connection that's supposed to only give me printable characters, but in reality that's not always the case. I've seen some binary zeros in there, at the start and end of some fields. I have no control over the source of the data and I need to process the "dirty" lines. If I could just filter out the invalid characters, that'd be OK. The relevant code is as such:

```
srvr = new ServerSocket(myport);
skt = srvr.accept();
// Tried with no encoding argument too
in = new Scanner(skt.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
in.useDelimiter("[\r\n]");
for (;;) {
    String myline = in.next();
    if (!myline.equals(""))
        ProcessRecord(myline);
}
```

I get an exception at every line that has "dirt." What's a good way to filter out invalid characters while still being able to obtain the rest of the string?

Comment: Whats the exception you are getting?

Comment: Ideally your protocol should be freed of "dirt". My answer would be: why are you getting "dirt" in your communication line?. Improve your protocol and then you won't have to deal with it.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, it's true, but sometimes you can't. I had the same identical problem while scraping web pages, and couldn't ask the webmaster to fix the server settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purest solution is to filter the InputStream (binary bytes-level I/O).

```
in = new Scanner(new DirtFilterInputStream(skt.getInputStream()), "Windows-1252");

public class DirtFilterInputStream extends InputStream {

    private InputStream in;

    public DirtFilterInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int ch = in.read();
        if (ch != -1) {
            if (ch == 0) {
                ch = read();
            }
        }
        return ch;
    }

}
```

(You need to override all methods, and delegate to the original stream.)
Windows-1252 is Windows Latin-1, an extended Latin 1, ISO-8859-1, using 0x80 - 0xBF.

Comment: Instead of those two if's, I used:while (((ch < 32) || (ch > 127)) && (ch != 13) && (ch != 10) && (ch != -1)) {
            ch = read();
        }

Comment: Then you should use `in.read()` as my recursive readCh is ugly. P.S. do not forget to override the other methods too.

Comment: It did work overriding just that one. Maybe because that particular stream is used only for continuously reading data in that loop and nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

You have to wrap your `InputStream` in a `CharsetDecoder`, defining an empty error handler:

```
//let's create a decoder for ISO-8859-1 which will just ignore invalid data
CharsetDecoder decoder=Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newDecoder();
decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
//let's wrap the inputstream into the decoder
InputStream is=skt.getInputStream();
in = new Scanner(decoder.decode(is));
```

you can also use a custom `CodingErrorAction` and define your own action in case of coding error.

Comment: Thanks! I encountered this problem while scraping web pages in German

Answer (score 0):

I was completely off base. I get the "dirty" strings no problem (and NO, I have NO option to clean up the data source, it's from a closed system and I have to just grin and deal with it) but trying to store them in PostgreSQL is what gets me the exception. That means I have total freedom to clean it up before processing.

Comment: Honesty appreciated. Accept your own answer, so SO visitors know to skip.

Comment: Actually, I used YOUR solution, even though I could treat the string after getting it. I found it neater.